# Windows 10 not recognizing Seagate USB 3.0 external drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, windows-10, external-hard-drive, device-manager

I have a lot of data in my USB 3.0 external drive from Seagate but since this morning Windows 10 does open it.

If I open "My PC" I can see the G: Drive in there but has no name or disk information regarding free and occupied space. The light is always blinking, no stop.

I've googled and found this link http://www.thewindowsclub.com/usb-3-0-external-hard-drive-not-recognized but I'm stuck on the first step. I'm trying to uninstall the drive via Device Manager but the operation doesn't seem to finish and the Uninstalling loading screen does not disappear.

I really don't want to unplug the cable while this operation is doing. I'm afraid of breaking the drive even more.

**Note**:
I've tried the drive on an Ubuntu live disto. That's always the first thing I do since it already worked a couple of time with other disk drives. It recognizes the drive and I can see the alias, but when I try to open it gives an error saying an operation is pending.

Comment: did you try the drive on another computer?

Comment: Try it on another computer or boot into a Linux live distribution. No drivers are necessary, Windows XP and newer will automatically install the correct drivers and mount the partitions. This is the exact issue I had with my Toshiba Canvio drive, it would show up in Device Manager and Disk Management, but could not be accessed. In my instance it was faulty case (USB-SATA adapter inside the case), but what you describe is common behavior of a faulty drive.

Comment: Oh, and if you are scared to just unplug the drive (which is probably not relevant now), you could always do a shutdown of the machine it is plugged into first.

Comment: I've tried the drive on an Ubuntu live disto. That's always the first thing I do since it already worked a couple of time with other disk drives. It recognizes the drive and I can see the alias, but when I try to open it gives an error saying an operation is pending.

Comment: After almost 3 hours, windows 10 sucessfully uninstalled the disk driver. I rebooted the system and tried again, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to make Windows 10 recognize the drive again. I even try using chkdsk with different arguments but an error would always break the process. I was able to recover all the data using Seagate Recovery for Windows and then recreate the partitions using Windows Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue and none of the answers helped me.
What struck me as strange is that when I log on to Linux, the hard drive works without any problems.
For this reason I had discarded a malfunction of the device.
In my case I have been able to solve the problem in a much simpler way than I could have imagined.
I just followed...
Control Panel -> System -> Device Manager -> View -> Mark Show hidden devices -> Double-click the hidden device 
...and suddenly, the hard drive magically appears as an additional drive in the windows explorer.

Hidden hard drive:

[image]